# How to configure KDiff3 as merge tool for VSCode Editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to configure the KDiff3 as merge tool in VSCode?

Answer (score 1):

You can set it as a merge/diff tool for git, VSCode will use the default git tool anyway

Comment: Is this actually true? I've configured an external tool in .gitconfig and using `git difftool` works, but VSCode still uses the default diff tool. There doesn't seem to be any way to configure this behavior in VSCode settings.json either.